# How to add attributes to sku using Stripe dashboard?

Tags: stripe-payments

From the documentation, here is the description of a sku:

> Stores representations of stock keeping units. SKUs describe specific product variations, taking into account any combination of: attributes, currency, and cost. For example, a product may be a T-shirt, whereas a specific SKU represents the size: large, color: red version of that shirt.

I can see that my sku does not have any attribute here: 
[image]

But if I try editing my sku there is no field to add attributes:
[image]

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Regards

Comment: To add attributes to a SKU, the Product it's related to should have attributes defined. You need to update the product first to add attributes. I recommend not using SKUs and Attributes at all though, this was for Orders which is deprecated

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer it is very helpful. How should I store this information then ? (the size, color etc of clothes for example)

Comment: You would store this information on your end today. Or you could use https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata

Comment: OK thank you very much